# $(m,n)=1$ why is $(x,m,n)=1$ with $x=m^2-n^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Hi I have some problems with the next two thing of pythagorean triples and the GCD:

1) In early number theory we saw: if $(x,y)=(x,z)=(y,z)=1$ then $(x,y,z)=1$ but with Pythagorean triples we saw a lemma that says that if $(x,y,z)=1$ then $(x,y)=(x,z)=(y,z)=1$. Strange because in early number theory we say the first theorem and said that the other way is’t always true.

2) $(m,n)=1$ why is $(x,m,n)=1$ with $x=m^2-n^2$

Comment: By $(x,m,n)=1$ you mean that there is no natural number greater than $1$ that divides all three?  Well, if there were such a number it would divide $m,n$.

Comment: Ok and when it devides m and n, isnt it than possible that it also devides x?

Comment: $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1})$ must divide $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$.

Comment: Ok, Why is that true? It feels very strange to me. Do you have an example?

Comment: Because every common divisor of $n+1$ numbers is a common divisor of $n$ of these numbers. Just like if $n+1$ people have the same name, $n$ of these people have the same name.

Comment: Yes but we start from n number and then go to n+1. You go from n+1 to n?

Comment: If seven chairs are green, six of these chairs are also green. I find it rather obvious. I can't explain it further.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that $(x,y)=(y,z)=(x,z)=1$ implies $(x,y,z)=1$ for any $x,y,z$.  In fact, even $(x,y)=1$ implies $(x,y,z)=1$ for any $x,y,z$.  In that case we have $(x,y,z)=((x,y),z)=(1,z)=1$.

The converse is not always true.  We have $(6,10,15)=1$ but the $\gcd$ of any pair is greater than $1$.  However if you know $x^2+y^2=z^2$ you then have $(x,y,z)=1$ implies the pairwise $\gcd$s are $1$.  Note that $6^2+10^2\neq 15^2$, so that is not a counterexample to the proposition.  In the Pythagorean case, if you have $(x,y)\gt 1$, let $(x,y)=a$.  Then $x=ak, y=am$ for some $k,m.\quad x^2+y^2=z^2=(ak)^2+(am)^2=a^2(k^2+m^2)$ so $z$ has a factor $a$ as well and $(x,y,z)$ is at least $a$.  You can do the same for any other pair.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(m,n,m^2-n^2)=d$.

Thus, $m$ and $n$ they are divisible by $d$, which says $1$ is divisible by $d$, which says  that $d=1$.

Answer (score 0):

2) As lulu said in the comments, $(m,n) = 1$ means there is no positive integer other than $1$ which divides both $m$ and $n$. Now suppose $(m,n,x) = b >1$, i.e., there is some positive integer $b>1$ which divides all of $x$, $m$, and $n$. Then in particular it divides both $m$ and $n$, so we could not have $(m,n) = 1$.

1) It is in general not true that $(x,y,z) = 1 \implies (x,y) = (x,z) = (y,z) = 1$. For example, $(3,5,10)=1$ but $(5,10) = 5$. However, the case of Pythagorean triples is a special case. If it's a Pythagorean triple, we have $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. We will need to use the lemma that if $b > 1$ and $b|n^2$, then there is some $c >1$ (not necessarily identical to $b$) such that $c|b$ and $c|n$. This can be seen, e.g., by taking the prime factorization of $b$ and noting that each prime factor, since it appears at least once in $n^2$, must appear at least once in $n$.

Now we are assuming $(x,y,z)=1$. Suppose $(x,y) \neq 1$. Then we have some $b>1$ such that $b|x$ and $b|y$, so $b|(x^2+y^2)=z^2$. Then by the lemma there is some $c>1$ with $c|b|x$, $c|b|y$, and $c|z$, so $c|(x,y,z)$, contradicting $(x,y,z)=1$. So we must have $(x,y)=1$.

Now suppose $(x,z) \neq 1$. Then we have some $b>1$ such that $b|z$ and $b|x$, so $b|(z^2-x^2)=y^2$. Then by the lemma there is some $c>1$ such that $c|y$, and we proceed as in the previous case. The same argument goes through if we suppose $(y,z) \neq 1$. So we must have $(x,z)=(y,z)=1$.

As you can see, we make heavy use of the Pythagorean relationship between the three numbers -- it's this fact that allows the converse to be true, when it is not true in general.

Comment: So when we know $(m,n)=1$ then $(m,n,x)=1$ for every value of $x$. It has nothing to do with the fact that in this case  $x=m^2−n^2$?

Comment: @LeneCoenen Correct. The fact that it is a Pythagorean triple is important only for your first question.

Comment: Yes, but this step do I need for a proof about pythagorean triples, in that case was x=m2−n2. But is it true that when we know $(m,n)=1$ then $(m,n,x)=1$ for every value of $x$. It has nothing to do with the fact that in this case  $x=m^2−n^2$?

Comment: @LeneCoenen Correct.

Answer (score 0):

The converse in (a) is not generally true but it is true only for Pythagorean triplets. Let $(x,y,z)=1$. Let us assume $(x,y)=d>1$, then from $x^2+y^2=z^2$, we get $d\mid z$, hence $(x,y,z)=d$. Contradiction. If we assume $(x,z)=d>1$, then $y^2=z^2-x^2$, so $d\mid y$, contradiction again. Hence $(x,y,z)=1\implies(x,y)=(y,z)=(z,x)=1$.

Any Pythagorean triplet can be written as $$(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$$